# How to access a SQL database in visual studio? (Razor cshtml, C#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, razor

I Already connected my SQL database with visual studio via server explorer And i filled some tables with values.

Now, I want to access/search through a table from my SQL database in my visual studio project. 
For example: in my table i have products from different categories and i only want to display products from a specific category

But, how can in do that?

Comment: Menu => View => SQL Server Object Explorer

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Look into using EntityFramework entities. The inbuilt data wizards will generate all the classes you need to access your database using LINQ. Raw SQL commands are *so last century* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways by which you can access.If you are using connected mode Than you have to create object for connection string

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=nameof_server;Initial Catalog=name_of_database;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sql_command",con);
con.open()
//perform action based on your requirment
ExecuteNonQuery() // Use this for insert,update,delete

ExecuteScalar() // Use this for select single column

ExecuteReader() // Use this for select multiple records 
con.close()
```

[Please check this link](http://kushonline.blogspot.in/2012/07/connectivity-adonet-with-connected-mode.html)